# Python: Upsampling a non-constant & non-increasing signal

Tags: python, resampling

I have a signal that I would like to upsample e.g.

```
x=np.array([8,1,2,3,4,5])
y=np.array([3,1,8,4,0,2])
```

As you can see, the x has a non-constant sampling frequency. Furthermore, its values are not necessarily increasing. My original idea was to upsample x using the resampling function:

```
x_new=scipy.signal.resample(x, N_points, t=None, axis=0, window=None);
```

and then using the linear interpolation to find the values of y_new

```
y_new=np.interp(x_new,x,y);
```

However, linear interpolation seems not working if x data are not constantly increasing. Data are not periodic, so I can't take advantage of the period option. Any idea?

I was thinking of perhaps sorting x_new, and re-sorting is back after interpolating (it seems very inefficient and I am not even sure if feasible). Any more elegant solution?

Thanks for helping!